Asterisk glob expansion (*) unexpected behaviour in bash on WSL's 9P mounts
I'm observing strange behavior from my script only in WSL on 9P mounts (Windows disks, like /mnt/c/...).
Glob expantion of asterisk (*) in for loop results in duplicates on next invocation if there is a pipe that writes to temporary file.
#!/bin/bash

# save true file number
true_f_num=$(for fn in *; do echo; done | wc -l)

while :; do
    # count of iterations to outer loop pipe
    echo
    
    # save current file list in file
    echo -n '' >.list
    
    for fn in *; do
        echo "$fn" >>.list
    
    # line below causes unexpected behaviour
    # on 9P mounts (like /mnt/c/...)
    # (WSL2, ubuntu 22.04)
    done | cat > .tmp; rm .tmp
    
    # check 
    [ $(cat .list | wc -l ) -ne $true_f_num ] && break

done | wc -l


Here is a script jist to test and illustrate that. It is expected to run forever. But on WSL's 9P mounts it stops after some random number of iterations.
I can't understand the mechanism of this. I assumed that glob expansion happens once, and only later it starts being passed to the pipe (subshell) and changes the contents of directory. And how can this affect the next iteration? The file was there, but it's not anymore. Does some invisible fifo appear in the directory?
Please let the wise explain what is happening here.

@oguzismail ok, but star glob doesn't include other hidden files (dot-started names) with current options.

@oguzismail and, second, why is it observed ONLY on certain type of filesystem? This construction (though its doubtfull) was in my script for quite long time and it never fails, and now it's observed only on windows mounts in WSL, as I described.

And if it's race condition indeed, how can I reproduce the same behaviour on common (not WSL 9P) directories?

The race condition is triggered to problems on mounts because mounted paths have extra lag when performing operations and handling signalization. To solve this, no need to reproduce the lag. Just remove the race condition and adopt defensive coding practices.

@LéaGris thank you. But the question is not how to solve this, it's already solved. I'm trying to understand mechanics of this.

Have you checked the contents of .list when this happens? Do you see duplicate entries?

@oguzismail Yes and yes. And one of my the question is why does it show not a deleted file, but one of the existing files twice?

Is there some invisible fifo, and it counts that fifo, so the loop runs again, but somehow the name gets substituted? I can’t figure out how to dig into this.

Does it happen if you remove rm .tmp only? I wonder if this is a bug in bash or WSL

@oguzismail Yes. And I tried to modify the construction in different ways and see that it only happens this way: with pipe from loop and output redirection to current dir. I've also thought about bug, but again I don't know how to dig it further, so I've asked here.

I made this example simplifying my script just to show the situation. If I remove something, or modify, it runs forever, as intended.

"I assumed that glob expansion happens once, and only later it starts being passed to the pipe" -- yes. The shell performs pathname expansion on a command before it executes the command (each time it executes the command, if it appears in a loop or a function body).  After that and all other expansions, it performs redirections.  Only then does it actually execute the command itself.  This applies to simple and compound commands alike.

Side note: it's probably not related to the observed misbehavior, but the example script makes unnecessary use of cat. wc can accept the name of an input file as an argument, so you don't need to cat input into it from an existing file. And if you want wc to operate on input from a non-file source then there is no need to interpose cat between that source (your inner loop's output, in this case) and wc.

" I assumed that glob expansion happens once, and only later it starts being passed to the pipe" -- no. All stages in a pipeline run in parallel. The glob will be expanded at the same time that .tmp is created, which is likely the cause of the issue.

@JohnBollinger About | cat > .tmp
I've used this construction here intentionally. The described behaviour only appears with temporary file from pipe. There was sort and other useful stuff on pipe in actual script instead of cat. This script here is just for illustration.

@thatotherguy It intuitively seems true, and I’ll think about what test can confirm it. But why does a duplicate file appear in the list instead of .tmp? The file seems to get created during the explanation and deleted before the main part, but in such a way that some remnants are left? Is the inner part of the loop that reads files also happening simultaneously with a pipe? The explanation involving file system speed (mounted slower than native) seems odd. For this behaviour .tmp should be created/deleted faster than expansion/read.

@thatotherguy Unless expansion/reading in the case of WSL&9p is slower than creating/deleting a temporary one. Additionally, I've never observed such behavior, for example, on SMB shares.

Yes, the internal loop that reads the directory to expand * will happen in parallel with the redirection that creates the file. My best guess (which I have absolutely no evidence for) is that it's a bug/peculiarty in the 9p fs driver related to how the FD keeps its current position when the directory changes underneath it. This would be like how for(int i=0; i<dir.size(); i++) print(dir[i]); will print an entry twice if something happens to insert a new value earlier than the current i while it's running. Maybe strace can confirm whether this is what's happening.

@thatotherguy strace slows it down enough to avoid the race. In fact, on my laptop, this issue is only reproducible when the charger is plugged :D


[The example script] is expected to run forever. But on WSL's 9P mounts it stops after some random number of iterations.

Presumably that's because [ $(cat .list | wc -l ) -ne $true_f_num ] evaluates to true on some evaluation, and indeed, you observe in comments that after the script terminates, you find a duplicate name in the .list file left behind.  That would do it, unless you're also missing one name.
File .list is created and populated this way:

    echo -n '' >.list

    for fn in *; do
        echo "$fn" >>.list
        # [...]
    done | cat > .tmp


A rm .tmp follows, but that is not part of managing .list, and it is not executed until after the above pipeline completes.  However, because .tmp is removed after each execution of the pipeline, it is reasonable to assume that it does not exist before control reaches the pipeline.
Because the for command appears in a pipeline, it is executed in a subshell.
The pattern (*) within is expanded, in the subshell, producing one word per file, before that command is executed. Then the subshell's standard output is redirected into the pipe, and finally, the loop body is executed once for each word in the expansion of *.
At the same time, the standard input of cat is redirected from the pipe, its standard output is redirected to .tmp, first creating that file if necessary, and then cat is launched.
NOTE WELL, then, that it is unspecified and not generally predictable when .tmp will be created relative to the expansion of the * pattern in the for command.  It could be before, during, or after.
Observations:

by default, pathname expansion omits files whose names start with . unless the . is explicitly matched by the pattern.  Therefore, in the above code, .tmp is not expected to appear in the expansion of *, regardless of the relative timing of its creation.

in the example command, pathname expansion is expected to be performed, once, before any iterations of the loop body are performed.

it is not expected for pathname expansion to yield duplicate pathnames, because that is not consistent with the Bash or POSIX specifications.

Unless file .list is modified contemporaneously by something else not disclosed, the appearance of duplicate lines within indicates that at least one of the previous two expectations is violated.  This would be a bug.

It seems most likely to me that such a bug would be associated with the creation of file .tmp at an inopportune time during the evaluation of the pathname expansion.  I can think of at least one specific form of implementation flaw that might give rise to such an issue. This is of course speculative, but I think it plausible.



How can this affect the next iteration?

I think each iteration of the outer loop has its own, independent opportunity to trigger the bug.  And I think it's likely to be a bug in pathname expansion, so not an issue of one iteration of the inner loop affecting another, either.

Does some invisible fifo appear in the directory?

Unlikely.

So, the expansion and the pipe run simultaneously in their loop's and pipe's subshells. Time to time file creation-deletion in the pipe affects the expansion in such a way that one filename appears twice in the list, and this is likely to be a bug in the expansion implimentation.
In this case I should report this bug to WSL developers.
Thank you!

I used part on your response in the report, if you don't mind:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/12227
I think I’ll mark the question as closed, but I’ll wait a bit, just in case.

Side note on terminology, @daubmannus: a pipe is a passive data conduit.  It does not run at all.  A pipeline is a shell construct in which two or more commands are chained together with pipes.  Each command in a pipeline (e.g. for and cat, including their subshell contexts) runs concurrently with the others, and the overall pipeline can be considered to run until the rightmost command in it terminates, but there is no sense in which a pipeline itself runs separately from the commands from which it is composed.
